# Is "broad variety" in common usage? Better adjective?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

A colleague used "broad variety" which sounds odd to me. I would go for "wide range", but is there a commonly used adjective with "variety" that can be substituted?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broad+variety%2Cwide+variety%2Cwide+range%2Cbroad+range&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbroad%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwide%20variety%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwide%20range%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbroad%20range%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Use the wildcard in [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+*+variety+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ca%20*%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Ba%20great%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20wide%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20greater%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20large%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20vast%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20considerable%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20rich%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20wider%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20new%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ba%20bewildering%20variety%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Relevant results from the Google Ngram in my previous comment: *a wide variety, a great variety, a large variety, a rich variety, a bewildering variety, a considerable variety*, and *a vast variety*. The most common are *wide variety* and *great variety*.

Comment: What do you find wrong about the phrase other than a general feeling of malaise? Can you articulate your feelings? Is the pair pleonastic?

Answer (score 1):

Without consulting Ngram, I would have predicted that both "wide variety" and "broad range" are more common than "broad variety." And I would have been right: "broad variety" barely registers against those two, and "wide range" is even more common, as this Ngram chart of "wide variety" (blue line) vs. "broad range" (red line) vs. "wide range" (green line) vs. "broad variety" (yellow line) for the years 1800–2000 shows:

> [image]

So perhaps the reason "broad variety" sounds odd to you is that English writers use it far less often than they do the other three options tracked in the Ngram chart. Clearly, people use "wide variety" far more often than they do "broad variety," though the preference defies simple explanation.